# Need help creating a for loop array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I am new to Javascript and Node.js and I am currently trying to make a write a for loop and I am very stuck.

```
const url1 = options.url ? `https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(options.url)}&key=${escape(options.key)}` : "";
const url2 = options.url ? `https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(options.url2)}&key=${escape(options.key)}` : "";
const url3 = options.url ? `https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(options.url3)}&key=${escape(options.key)}` : "";
const url4 = options.url ? `https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(options.url4)}&key=${escape(options.key)}` : "";

const arr = [url1, url2, url3, url4]
```

The code above is what I currently have running and works fine, but I am trying to turn it into a loop, such as below.

```
const urlArray = [];
for (i = 1, i < 4; i++;) {
    const url(i) = options.url ? `https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(options.url(i))}&key=${escape(options.key)}` : "";
}

const arr = [url1, url2, url3, url4]
```

Note that I want the first const (url1) to have options.url instead of options.url1 because it further breaks the code and returns an error. please let me know if you have any tips or solutions

Also I will leave the options here incase it is crucial to figuring out the loop. It uses yargs to construct the options and axios to interact with the API.  It is important to note that the options are blank because I am building a CLI that takes several inputs from the user that are then inserted into different iterations of the urls and ran together.

```
const options = yargs
    .usage("Usage: -u <url>")
    .option("u", { alias: "url", describe: type: "string", demandOption: true })
    .option("s", { alias: "url2", describe: type: "string", demandOption: true })
    .option("d", { alias: "url3", type: "string", demandOption: true })
    .option("f", { alias: "url4", type: "string", demandOption: true })
    .option("k", { alias: "key", type: "string", demandOption: true })
    .argv;
```

Comment: I would be helpful if you posted the actual value of `const options` so that people who want to help you don't also have to know what `yargs.usage()...` does.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want the first url to be `url` instead of `url1`? Is this something you're unwilling to change?

Comment: Trying to replace those hardcoded four lines with a loop means you specifically *don't* use variables like `url1`. What you do instead is `const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter(key => !!options["url" + key]).map(key => \`https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(options["url" + key])}&key=${escape(options.key)}\`);`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help and comments, I guess that the first url could be changed to url1, but I ran into issues implementing the change into my current build. Also I don't have the value of the options provided because this is a CLI app build that takes input from a user and implements it into the ${escape(options.url)} and ${escape(options.key)} parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just completely guessing at what `options` looks like based on the code you posted, but does something like this work?

```js
const options = {
    url: 'x.com',
    url2: 'y.com',
    url3: 'z.com',
    url4: 'aa.com',

    key: 'key'
}

function getUrl(num) {
    if (num === 1) return options.url;
    const key = `url${num}`;
    return options[key];
}

const urlArray = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    const newUrl = options.url ? `https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(getUrl(i))}&key=${escape(options.key)}` : "";
    urlArray.push(newUrl);
}

console.log(urlArray);
```

Using a function to convert your iteration variable into the proper key in the object is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did not use this answer because the single line provided by ChrisG worked perfectly for me, but thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @lovecroatzia I hope you at least upvoted. This is a better answer, and is actually an answer VS a comment.

Comment: @AustinTFrench I don't have enough reputation to upvote but I greatly appreciate both of their help

Answer (score 0):

I used the comment from @Chris G to answer this question.

Trying to replace those hardcoded four lines with a loop means you specifically don't use variables like url1. What you do instead is

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter(key => !!options["url" + key]).map(key => `https://www.icanhazdadjoke.com?url=https://${escape(options["url" + key])}&key=${escape(options.key)}`);
```